# JQuery find last child in given div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to develop a web application where you can specify a question and then provide a choice of multiple answers. I require extra answer 'boxes' to be added when the plus button is clicked, but only added to the specific formRow (see code).
I have tried the JQuery last function but it will always add after the answer box with id=4.

HTML:

```
<div class="formRow">
                <a href="#" title="" class="Remove smallButton" style="float:right;"><img src="images/icons/color/cross.png" alt="" /></a>
                <label>Multiple Choice: </label>
                <div class="formRight" style="height:28px;">Question1: <input type="text" class="MCQuestion" QID="'+QID+'" /><a href="#" title="" class="AddAns smallButton" style="margin-left:5px;padding: 1px 3px;"><img src="images/icons/color/plus.png" alt="" /></a></div>
                <div class="formRight MCAns" id="1">Answer 1: <input type="text" class="MCAnswer"/><a href="#" title="" class="DelAns smallButton" style="margin-left:5px;padding: 1px 3px;"><img src="images/icons/color/cross.png" alt="" /></a></div>
                <div class="formRight MCAns" id="2">Answer 2: <input type="text" class="MCAnswer"/><a href="#" title="" class="DelAns smallButton" style="margin-left:5px;padding: 1px 3px;"><img src="images/icons/color/cross.png" alt="" /></a></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="formRow">
                <a href="#" title="" class="Remove smallButton" style="float:right;"><img src="images/icons/color/cross.png" alt="" /></a>
                <label>Multiple Choice2: </label>
                <div class="formRight" style="height:28px;">Question2: <input type="text" class="MCQuestion" QID="'+QID+'" /><a href="#" title="" class="AddAns smallButton" style="margin-left:5px;padding: 1px 3px;"><img src="images/icons/color/plus.png" alt="" /></a></div>
                <div class="formRight MCAns" id="3">Answer 1: <input type="text" class="MCAnswer"/><a href="#" title="" class="DelAns smallButton" style="margin-left:5px;padding: 1px 3px;"><img src="images/icons/color/cross.png" alt="" /></a></div>
                <div class="formRight MCAns" id="4">Answer 2: <input type="text" class="MCAnswer"/><a href="#" title="" class="DelAns smallButton" style="margin-left:5px;padding: 1px 3px;"><img src="images/icons/color/cross.png" alt="" /></a></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").on("click", ".AddAns", function(event) {
    $(".MCAns").last().after("New Answer Optition"); //Tried this first
    $(".MCAns :last-child").after("New Answer Optition"); //Then this
});
});
```

Comment: Where is the `.AddAns` button?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon In the first formRight class, just after the Question input box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".AddAns", function(event) {
        $(this).closest('.formRow').find('.MCAns').last().after("New Answer Optition");
    });
});
```

The probleme with your code is that you are selecting every `MCAns` and take the last one. You should take the last of `.formRow` add button you clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Use that code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").on("click", ".AddAns", function(event) {
    $('.formRow').find('.MCAns').last().after("New Answer Optition");
});
});
```

Check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5vN5/)

Comment: This didn't work sorry, It added the new option to more than one element.

Comment: I fix it, look at js fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the container `formRow` first, then you can add as many tags as you want.
Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".AddAns", function(event) {
      var parent = $(this).parents('.formRow'); // Find the container .formRow first
      parent.find('.MCAns:last').after("New Answer Optition"); // Add new content after last one
  });
});
```